# Python: get items from itemlist

Tags: python

I'm python newbie and found something difficult while doing some practices.

I have few def functions under a class look like:

```
Class A(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.itemID = []
        self.itemlist = []

    def add(self, ID, list):

        self.itemID.append(ID)
        self.itemlist.append(list)

    def get_item(self,ID):

        self.ID = ID
        result = []
        for self.ID in self.itemlist:
            result.append(self.itemlist)
        return result
```

I'm having problems with "def get_item". Here's an example..

if i do:

```
A.add('abc', 'bcd')

A.add('abc1', 'bcd1')

A.get_item('abc')
```

This should return abc, bcd but mine returns [['bcd', 'bcd1'], ['bcd', 'bcd1']]...

Apologise for the long complicated dumb looked codes.... Any feedbacks would be so appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your get_item function is absolutely wrong :)

Here's how it should look like:

```
def get_item(self,ID):
  result = []
  for x in range(0, len(self.itemID)):
      if (self.itemID[x] == ID):
          result.append(self.itemlist[x])
  return result
```

Or even better:

```
def get_item(self, ID):
   return [self.itemlist[x] for x in range(0, len(self.itemID) if self.itemID[x] == ID]
```

Now, if I understand the logic behind your class, you want to be able to retrieve a list of object given a common ID. This can be better done using a dict

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.content  = {}

   def add(self, ID, object):
       list = self.get_item(ID)
       list.append(object)
       content[ID] = list

   def get_item(self, ID):
       return content.get(ID, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `dict`?

```
A = {}
A['abc'] = 'bcd'
A['abc1'] = 'bcd1'
```

Then, `A['abc']` returns `'bcd'`, as you want.

You can access the IDs with `A.keys()` and the items `A.values()` so you don't lose any functionality.

As @Stals points out in the comments, if you want to retain the order that you add things, you can also use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

If you really need more than one item with the same ID, there are various `multidict` recipes that might work.

Comment: I guess, the reason is that because he wants to have multiple items with the same ID. Can also be done using a dict. Just not as simple as  the given example.

Comment: well, he is trying to return a list of objects. and there is no control over the existence of ID in the add function. Unless, it is a complete misconception :)

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained how to make it work; I'm going to explain why what you had doesn't work.

The problem here is that Python is doing exactly what you tell it to do:

```
for self.ID in self.itemlist:
         result.append(self.itemlist)
```

1. In a loop, set `self.ID` to each element of `self.itemlist` in order. (By the way, it is entirely unnecessary to use an instance attribute for this since there's no need to keep the `ID` when the method is done; you should probably use a local variable here instead.)
2. Each time through the loop, append a reference to `self.itemlist` to the result.

In other words, you are asking for individual items from your `self.itemlist`, but not doing anything with the items. All your append operations append *the original list,* not the current item from the list.

As a result, your method returns a list with as many copies of `self.itemlist` as there are elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_item` code is very confused. It overwrites `self.ID`, several times, when it should only read it, and the loop appends the *entire itemlist* (or, rather, the itemlist itself) to the result - and it does this at every iteration. This is why you are seeing such a strange result.

What you are probably thinking of is this:

```
def get_item(self, ID):
   for index in range(self.ID.length):
      if self.id[index] == ID:
         return self.itemlist[index]
```

That is: iterate over the indexes of both lists, and when you find the one that has a matching ID at that position in the ID list, return the thing in the corresponding position in `itemlist`.

This code can be improved a bit by using Python's built-in functions. For example, you could use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) - which can take both your lists (`ID` and `itemlist`), and give you back pairs of corresponding items - so, you have:

```
def get_item(self, ID):
    for id, item in zip(self.ID, self.itemlist):
        if id == ID:
            return item
```

But you can get rid of the loop entirely by using [list methods](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) - `list.index` does the search for you:

```
def get_item(self, ID):
   return self.itemlist[self.ID.index(ID)]
```